# Data Tables Columns

Tags: jquery, datatables

Is there a way to use datatables plug-in for Jquery and have the data determine the number of columns, and not the other way around?

I currently have a problem where the data that comes in is varied depending on users, but datatables seems to require me to specify the number columns I want to display BEFORE the data comes in.

Thanks

Comment: How you are rendering table?using JS?

Comment: you can try to render the table thead via JS accordingly to your data result but i think you migh have the problem with the titles of those dynamic columns. but there's some problems with this approach, since you rendering columns using the result you have to think the scenario when you have no result to rely on. so at the end i don't encourage you to take that advice